# Preventing Network Interface from changing speed ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, 22.04

Currently i'm stuck in trying to make my server a reliable router. It keep dropping the connection randomly. After checking and debugging for some time, i finally find out the problem.

The connection drop only happened when my interface, either it's the WAN or LAN interface changing speed from 100mbps to 1gbps and vice versa. I can test the ping when it change the speed, either by using `ethtool` or it's own, the ping resulted around `700ms` from normally `0-1ms` which is enough to drop connection in online gaming/video call.

So my question is, is there a way to either:

- Force the speed into 1gbps, not allowing it to change at all
- Force the speed on 100mbps, then i will just use the line as dedicated internet, and i will give another network card for my file server
- Better solution to my problem?

I have tried many things, including `ethtool`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after several days digging, i finally found the issue.
the issue **wasn't**:

- bad cable
- bad switch
- bad NIC
- or anything physical there

So actually, i'm using `dnsmasq` as the DNS and DHCP server for my home network. When you start `dnsmasq`, by default it will fail because the service of `systemd-resolved` is using same port `53` which is used by DNS. Many online guide on using `dnsmasq` is asking to just disable the `systemd-resolved` by using `systemctl disable`, but many source actually say that this service is very important for entire system and do it at your own risk.

So i decided to backup most of my home server settings, and then i reinstall the ubuntu and do some testing. In that testing on fresh system, i do find that the ethernet speed and negotiation are stable. So here my testing:

I tested that fresh system as only NAS for 1 day, without using it as DHCP and DNS server. `PASS`

I then reconfigure that system with `dnsmasq` but this time i dont disable `systemd-resolved`, but instead i follow the guide here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/ubuntu-how-to-free-up-port-53-used-by.html.

1. `vim /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`
2. add `DNSStubListener=no`
3. reboot system

And viola! now my home server work perfectly even better than my router, using my old gaming pc:

- Gigabyte X79 UD3
- i7 3820
- 32GB Corsair Dominator 1600 C9
- 4x4 TB HDD in raid z1
- 1 NVMe for main purpose
- 64GB Sandisk USB 3.2 as boot
- Realtek 8125 PCIe 2.5gbe 4 port

And there we go!

Answer (score 0):

Speed changes usually indicate that the physical cable is bad, bent or otherwise broken.  Please try another network cable first.

Comment: it's same with other known good cables, at 1000mbps also it works just fine, it just that it sometimes change speed to 100mbps when not being used, but the moment it's used to the 1gbps, it spent 700ms to change to to 1gbps, same with changing back to 100mbps

Comment: Trouble is, if you fix the speed, then the computer will just disconnect you instead of reducing speed.  I'll assume that's worse.

Comment: Yes that happens too, but i notice that my windows machine always running on 1gbps all time with no issue, i can monitor this from my router. Cant ubuntu do the same?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu will also do the same, if in any way possible.  Have you tried swapping the ends of the network cable (it forces you to disconnect and re-route the cable)?

Comment: yes, i even tried to change to the know good cable, no luck

Comment: If the cable really is known good, then it must be something else.  Did you try another outlet in the router?  If not that, then look at the dmesg output for some details about the reasons for the speed change, but then I'm not really able to help you with the issue.

Comment: i found the issue, has been testing for 3 days and it's stable now, check my answer